# Displaying content above bootstrap nav tabs?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement the Nav tabs markup in a page, as defined in bootstrap. However, I want to place the content, which appears on clicking each tab, ABOVE the tabs, as opposed to the traditionally placed contents below the tabs.

In simple words, I want to switch the positions of "tabs" and "tab content".

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the position of the tabs and the tab-content by placing the tab-content over the tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE** Get the tabs to show upside down

To get the tabs to show upside down you can overwrite bootstrap's default css with

```
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
  margin:-1px;
}
```

Here is an updated Bootply
http://www.bootply.com/K8HhVqoz08

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Well it certainly switches the content.
But if you observe the CSS for active tab, it is not so cool. Because the content is above and its styling is embracing "some imaginary content" downwards. Agreed ?

Comment: @NewBee Is this more or less what you were trying to do?

Comment: @RedHat, it's probably 30% of the job. I want to modify the css as well, as per my above comment

Comment: @Redhat : Thanks. That's perfect ! Exactly what's needed.